# Are there stories on gods turning into mortals, or losing immortality?

Tags: magic, immortality

Besides the story in which Zeus turned Apollo and Poseidon into mortals once, are there more examples of gods losing their immortality in other mythologies as well? Not only in Greek Mythology.

Comment: There are numerous examples of mortals becoming immortal (see, for instance ["How do people become immortal as per Taoism?"](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/2022/2892) ), but fewer cases of the reverse.  I'm going to set my mind to this, and see what bubbles up.  Welcome to Mythology.  Great question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any Greek myths of a god permanently turning into a mortal as punishment?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/are-there-any-greek-myths-of-a-god-permanently-turning-into-a-mortal-as-punishme)

Comment: @バカです Answers part of question.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo  I think your Harmonia answer from the other thread could be resurrected here! (Ideally, you should look to support the answer with the source material, as opposed to just Riordan though;)

Comment: @DukeZhou I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another time Apollo was made mortal. After Zeus found out Apollo possessed the full gift of prophesy, he asked him which woman would give birth to the kid that would over throw him as king. Apollo backed away and said, "No can tell pops." Zeus got so angry, he was made mortal.

The next time Apollo was made mortal, Asclepius (as a demigod) brought back a dead person for Artemis. Hades complained, Zeus killed him. Apollo got mad, he killed the elder cyclops. Zeus got mad and was going to throw him into Tartarus, but made him mortal and brought back Asclepius as a god for a compromise.